# Exponential Sum - Solve for X

Tags: exponentiation

I'm wondering if there is a way to solve for x given the following equation:

$$A^x + B^x = C^x$$

where A, B, and C are known constants. For pythagorean triples, $x = 2$. I've seen a lot of stuff for sums of exponents (often using Taylor expansion) but I'm wondering if fixing it to 2 or 3 terms provides any shortcuts?

Another way to represent the problem could be finding the zeroes of the function

$$f(x) = A^x + B^x + C^x$$

WolframAlpha is somehow able to solve it but I'm not sure exactly what they are doing.

Comment: For your expression $f(x)=$ you need a minus sign on $C^x$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha uses some sort of numerical method. There is no "algebraic" solution except for limited cases.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah I realize the C in the second isn't the same as the C in the first, it has the opposite sign. They are still both constants though so the expression for x should be the same

Comment: @mattedgod you're wrong. $A^x+B^x+C^x$ doesn't have zeros.

Comment: @Kaster wouldn't that depend on the values of A, B, and C?

Comment: @mattedgod have you ever seen negative value for exponential function?

Comment: @Kaster No but I haven't really seen that many exponential functions :) That does make me curious about how you would go about solving that though, surely $(-1)^x$ has solutions, even if they are imaginary, right?

Comment: @mattedgod Please, show at least one root of the equation $(-1)^x = 0$.

Comment: Tag ([tag:exponential-sum]) is not good choice for this question, as you can see if you read the tag-excerpt of [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/exponential-sum/info). But I was not able to think of a better tag than ([tag:exponentiation]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpha is doing a numeric solution to the equation.  You can tell because the answer comes out as a decimal, not as some expression in roots.  Techniques for this are discussed in any numerical analysis book.  I like chapter 9 of [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html)-old versions are free online, but any other text will have it as well.

Comment: Ah I figured this was what they were doing. The expression seems so simple it would seem like it would have a formulaic solution but looks can be deceiving.